# How to deduce number of possible states for an adder

Tags: hardware

If my calculation is correct, a 4-bit adder has 65536 states which is exactly 2¹⁶. Where does this number come from? It seems there should be some theoretical background why this number is exactly 2¹⁶. Is it true, according to a general formula or is my model faulty?

My adder looks according to the following specification.

```
MODULE bit-adder (in1, in2, cin)
VAR
    sum : boolean;
    cout : boolean;
ASSIGN
    next (sum) := (in1 xor in2) xor cin;
    next (cout) := (in1 & in2) | ((in1 | in2) & cin);
MODULE adder (in1, in2)
VAR
    bit0 : bit-adder (in1[0], in2[0], FALSE);
    bit1 : bit-adder (in1[1], in2[1], bit0.cout);
    bit2 : bit-adder (in1[2], in2[2], bit1.cout);
    bit3 : bit-adder (in1[3], in2[3], bit2.cout);
DEFINE
    sum0 := bit0.sum;
    sum1 := bit1.sum;
    sum2 := bit2.sum;
    sum3 := bit3.sum;
    overflow := bit3.cout;
```

It is the number of states from my main module that is reported. If I don't include the main module then the number of states is 1.

```
MODULE main

VAR
    in1 : array 0 .. 3 of boolean;
    in2 : array 0 .. 3 of boolean;
    a : adder (in1, in2);
ASSIGN
    next (in1[0]) := in1[0];
    next (in1[1]) := in1[1];
    next (in1[2]) := in1[2];
    next (in1[3]) := in1[3];
    next (in2[0]) := in2[0];
    next (in2[1]) := in2[1];
    next (in2[2]) := in2[2];
    next (in2[3]) := in2[3];
DEFINE
    op1 := toint (in1[0]) + 2 * toint (in1[1]) + 4 * toint (in1[2]) + 8 * toint
    (in1[3]);
    op2 := toint (in2[0]) + 2 * toint (in2[1]) + 4 * toint (in2[2]) + 8 * toint
    (in2[3]);
    sum := toint (a.sum0) + 2 * toint (a.sum1) + 4 * toint (a.sum2) + 8 * toint
    (a.sum3) + 16 * toint (a.overflow);

    LTLSPEC F op1 + op2 = sum
```

It is when I add the row `a : adder (in1, in2);` that the number of states increases from 2^8 to 2^16. So it is something with the model checker and the main module.

Comment: So your adder doesn't use a carry-in, but produces a carry-out? Seems a little short-sighted, but just asking to make sure that I am gathering your intent correctly from your source.

Comment: @jonk I took it from lecture notes online but I had to change it. Now it seems to verify if my verification and model are right. I can try an 8-bit adder and see how many states are possible if there is double exponential growth in number of states.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the space representing all possible independent states is not necessarily the same as the subset of states that can be "walked through." I usually just visualize the case of all possible states as a hypercube with vertices and edges between them and then recognize that not all vertices can be reached after imposing rules that restrict edge options. But maybe I misunderstand your question. If so, that's my fault.

Comment: I really don't see an adder as having states at all. I see it as a pure combinational machine with no internal states, but maybe it is my fault

Comment: There are only 2^8 input states (ignoring carry inputs) and 2^5 possible output values.  I don't see how you can come up with 2^16.

Comment: Considering there are no latches or flops in most adders (except for input/output boundary), and that they are purely combinational, I would say they have one state.  In your example your outputs are flopped but this is not necessarily standard so no empirical formulas exist.  But in your case it is the same as the possible # of outputs

Comment: @jonk: everyone has different mental models for these types of mental abstraction.  very different usually.  for him to try to understand yours is probably not going to work out very well.  it is intuitive to you for a reason, others find other representations more intuitive.

Comment: @jbord39 yeah. I don't intend on writing a chapter on the way I see things. So it doesn't really matter. I was just attempting to see if the OP would comment in order to clarify the question being asked. But I think it relates to some compiler report he is getting and since I don't have the tools I can't interpret any of that.

Comment: I suspect you should go back to your notes. 2^16 is correct for an 8-bit adder, not for a 4-bit.

Comment: @jonk I updated the question with new findings. If I only check the adder then the number of states is 1. The number of input states are 2^8. It's when I add my main module that the state explosion occurs in the line `a : adder (in1, in2)` . So it is something with the main module and not the adder. I agree the number of input states is 2^8 for a 4-bit adder and 2^16 for an 8-bit adder.